# SSRS get value from specific row and column

Tags: reporting-services

What I would like to get is the Gross Margin % of the Revised Budget cell (11%) and place in a text box at the top of the page so it stands out a little more.

This is my current dataset output and also what is rendered in the table.

| Header | Original Budget | Change Orders | Revised Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contract Value | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| Labor | 500 | 500 | 100 |
| Gross Margin % | 10% | 10% | 11% |

I have tried using some IIF statements but that seems to only pull from the aggregate of the dataset and have looked at the LOOKUP function but that seems to only target a row.

```
Something I tried that isn't working - doesn't look right anyway

=Fields!Header.Value = "Gross Margin %" and Fields!Revised_Budget.Value = "Revised Budget"
```

If someone could point me in the direction of the correct function that would be great.

Running SSRS 2012.

Here is the report design
[image]

Comment: Share you report design. The important parts are `a.` any groupings `b.` any expressions currently being used. If you can also share what the dataset query results look like so we know what you data structure is then you'll get an answer pretty quickly I think. There are too many possibilities at the moment that depend on the report design.

Comment: I posted a pic but the dataset query results look like the how the table is rendered above.

Answer (score 0):

The row you need the value from is a group total, then you should be able to use the ReportItems collection and add a reference to actual textbox.

In your example, click the cell that you want to repeat (the one at the bottom of your report) and find its name from the properties panel, some like `TextBox99`.

Then in the textbox at the top, set the expression to

```
=ReportItems!textBox99.Value
```

That should be it.

Comment: I get this error - The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox27' refers to the report item 'Revised_Budget5'.  Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope. Letters in the names of report items must use the correct case.

Comment: That probably means the the textbox "Revised_Budget5" is repeated in the report (assuming that it is spelled correctly, it is case sensitive). Otherwise it should work. I just tested this on a simple exmaple it worked as expected.

Comment: It is repeated.  I wanted to have a line break (empty row) in my table between certain rows that I couldn't figure out how to do so I created 5 tables and used an expression based on a Tier classification to hide specific row.

Comment: I think it might be hard to answer without being able to see the report and investigate the design, the underlying data etc... Can you edit the image you shared of the report design and extend it to show the row and column groups panels (under main design window) and click the main table so it shows the groupings in the left column too. Then also share the expression that currently sits in the cell you want to repeat. I'll take another look if I get time but it's 9.30 pm here so it might not be for a few days.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to you.  I ended up using the LOOKUP function that I posted above.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted in the end. You can accept your own answer, so that the question appears answered. This helps other find answers to similar questions and saves others from looking at questions that appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [Lookup function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver16).  The first value is name of the value from the Header column that I was looking for.  The last value is the which data I want to return and that is the Revised_Budget value from the ProjectCosts dataset.

```
=LOOKUP(
  "Gross Margin %",
  Fields!Header.Value,
  Fields!Revised_Budget.Value, "ProjectCosts"
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.